# Custom Animations in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uiimage

hello i have this simple animation here that slides photos automatically.i just want to add extra effects on the slides thing like flipping or fading.please help me

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    imageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                                 [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"], nil];

    imageView.animationDuration = 15.00; //5 seconds each
    imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0; //infinite
    [imageView startAnimating]; //start the animation
}
```

Comment: It's a little unclear what you're asking. Are you trying to animate the UIImageView that displays the series of images, or are you trying to animate each image individually?

Comment: yes i want to animate the series of images not each image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that, you're going to need to go past UIImageView's animationImages property and manage the animations yourself using UIView transitionWithView and nest such. Like so.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"];
} completion:^(BOOL done){
    [UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
} completion:^(BOOL done){
        [UIView transitionWithView:imageView duration:5 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromBottom animations:^{
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
} completion:^(BOOL done){
        }];
    }];
}];
```

Comment: To repeat it, you just need to put that in a separate method, and set an NSTimer to call it every 15 seconds.